# iOS leaks : Who is the responsible?

Tags: ios, memory, memory-leaks, instruments

I'm profiling my application using the leak instrument, and I have some leaks. If I look in the responsible library column I can only see some frameWork library (mostly ImageIO).I would like to know if there is a way to know if a leak come from my code or is something related to the framework itself. For example if I select a leak and I look in the extended detail the stack trace there is no reference to my code (see image below)

[image]

I am a bit confused about that, could be possible that I don't see any reference to my code but the leak is somehow related to it? and if yes what could be the best strategy to discover who is leaking?

Any help / suggestions / tutorial is welcome

Comment: To me it looks like you are kicking off a separate thread without setting up an autorelease pool and/or not releasing core foundation objects properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in image, just change the settings like:

Select Call tree, and then on left hand side check: Invert Call tree, Hide-System Libraries and Show Obj-c only

Now if you are getting leaks then you can get hint of where is your code leaking

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer I did what you suggested, and no leaks are shown but the app still leak memory (just unchecking the options in call tree), based on your answer I should think I'm not the responsible?

Comment: @elio.d, there may be two possibilities now:
You are not responsible for leak, may be the library is having some leaks, OR sometimes instruments could not detect the leaks, so try clean and profile your project again, and still not resolved then try to read memory allocation guidelines by apple and just follow them very strictly, thats only we can do now buddy..